# How can I grep the output of a man page?

Tags: command-line, grep

I'm seeking the man page info for a switch for a given command.

I tried for example `man sort | grep -A2 "-n,"`.
I expected something like:

> -n, --numeric-sort
>
> ```
>     compare according to string numerical value
> ```

as output and instead I got

> Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
> Try 'grep --help' for more information.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that `-e` is the required switch for `grep` to protect a pattern beginning with a hyphen (-) so to get the expected result the command would be: `man sort | grep -A2 -e "-n,"`

which results in:

```
-n, --numeric-sort
              compare according to string numerical value

--
              sort according to WORD: general-numeric -g, human-numeric -h, month -M, numeric -n, random -R, version -V

       -V, --version-sort
```

And if I want only the first 2 lines of matching output providing exactly what I expected I have to further pipe it through `head` as in `man sort | grep -A2 -e "-n," | head -2`

Comment: or `grep -A2 -- "-n,"` which is telling `grep` there is no option later

Comment: no. See `man grep`

Answer (score 1):

You can also escape the `-n` using `\`

```
man sort | grep -A2 "\-n,"
```

Output:

```
      -n, --numeric-sort
              compare according to string numerical value

--
              month -M, numeric -n, random -R, version -V

       -V, --version-sort
```